# Rails partial form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, partial-views

I have a Bootstrap modal which is rendered via a Rails partial, I need this modal to be shared with the **new** and **edit** Rails views. In this partial there is a list of some users which I need them to be checked and when the user saves it a param is sent to the main view (new or edit) with user's selection. Also I need this partial to have the already selected users when it is popped from the edit view. ***So how to accomplish this?***

Here is a screenshot for it:[image]

I need a checkbox under the select column for each user, also send the selected to the "caller view" if it is right to call it so!

**The code inside my new view**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :members %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <% if user.empty? %>
      <p>Cannot assign memebers<p>
    <% else %>
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Select Members
      </button>
      <%= render 'layouts/select_user' %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the partial view called `"layouts/_select_user.html.erb"`

```
<!-- Bootstrap Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Select Available Members</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
          <th>Select</th>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>Job Title</th>
        </tr>

        <% User.where(:manager => false, :admin => false, :locked => false, :company_id => nil).each do |user| %>

        <tr>
          <td><%#= checkbox here  %></td>
          <td><%= link_to user.username.capitalize, edit_admin_user_path(user) %></td>
          <td><%= user.job_title %></td>
        </tr>

        <% end %>
      </table>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are asking how to accomplish this, it may be helpful to supply us with some of the view and controller code that you have tried this with.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you're trying to update multiple User objects (by selecting a checkbox next to each user object).

First of all running queries from the gui is not the best approach, populate those user objects from your controller actions (new/edit). You can then pass the collection of User object to the partial via the `:locals` hash:

```
def new
  @users = User.where(:manager => false, :admin => false, :locked => false, :company_id => nil)
end

<%=render :partial => 'layouts/select_user', :locals => {:users => @users}
```

Now, in your partial, instead of calling the query directly, you can use the @users variable.

The checkbox reference seems quite loose to me.  What does it mean in terms of the User object?  Would this value change the meaning of your User object (say it's a boolean which tells you if the user belongs to a certain type: employee,employer,etc).  If yes, add a new field to your users table.  You can use this new field for your checkbox.

Now as for updating those users, enclose @users object in a form and create a controller action to handle this update.  When you submit the form from the modal, it will send you an array of form objects.  You can iterate through those form objects from your controller action and process objects accordingly.

Here's a [good example](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/rails-update-multiple-records) on using multiple forms to update multiple objects.

Also checkout Ryan Bates' railscasts episode on the same topic:
[Complex Form 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1)
[Complex Form 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/74-complex-forms-part-2)
[Complex Form 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/75-complex-forms-part-3)

Comment: I need the checkbox to select some users and then add them to an organization (organization has an association of has_many users)

Comment: My problem is how the partial can give the (new and edit views) the selected users so they use them to create an organization or edit existing one?

Comment: I watched the episodes but I didn't figure out how to use fields_for for my specific case, I don't need to add a column to the users table just for selecting them in the view, it doesn't make sense, it is actually a view work and not related to the database. Also thanks for the code you provided, I refactored my view and moved the query to the controller.

Comment: As for your comment #2, your form is going to be in the partial, the submit action of which will forward the form contents (your updated selectboxes) to the controller.  Just like the create/update actions, you'll need to create one more action to handle multiple user objects.

Comment: But I don't want that to happen, I will give you a screenshot for my new view maybe it clarify what I want to do.

Comment: Regarding comment #3, the railscasts episodes were more like references of how this works.  For your specific use case, the example : http://www.dzone.com/snippets/rails-update-multiple-records that I quoted above, will help you solve your problem.

Comment: here is a part from my new view, the button "Select member" triggers the modal in which the user selects some "users" and when save the number of selected updated and user can create the organization. http://imagebin.org/291012

Comment: Quoting from the "dzone" example "<td><%= report_fields.check_box :current %></td>" the checkbox here manipulates a database column which is not the same as my case.

Comment: it's still a bit fuzzy.  do you want actions performed on the partial to affect your new/edit views?

Comment: The scenario goes like this, when user create a new organization he needs to add some users to it so he click on the "Select Members (0 selected)" button in the image in my comment. A modal pops up with a list of users each with a checkbox beside it. The user select some of them, then hit save button on the modal. The "select members (4 selected)" button in create organization view (new) updated with the number of selected users. And user now can hit "Create" to create and save the organization to db. Thats all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46873/discussion-between-rb512-and-wazery)

Answer (score -1):

There is no 'caller' because your modal view is an inline HTML, so you should be able to access the modal form data

Comment: I need a way to accomplish what I described in the question, how to add a checkbox beside each user and how the partial (modal) could pass the selected users back to its parent view?

Comment: As I said, there is no parent view. If you have your "render 'layouts/select_user'" inside the form_tag in the 'new' view, once you submit the form all the values from the partial will be sent, so you only have to add f.check_box in the partial. Pass the form in the local assigns to have access to the variable from your partial